# Flask event stream app with js eventsource overwrites previous stream output

Tags: javascript, flask

My flask app:

```
import eventlet

eventlet.monkey_patch()

from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from shelljob import proc
from time import sleep

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('stream.html')

@app.route('/stream')
def stream():
    g = proc.Group()
    p = g.run([ "bash", "-c", "sudo tcpdump -i ens4 -s 0 -nX tcp port 5000" ])
    def read_process():
        while g.is_pending():
            lines = g.readlines()
            for proc, line in lines:
                yield "data:" + str(line) + "\n\n"

    return Response(read_process(), mimetype='text/event-stream')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001)
```

**stream.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Output</h1>
    <div id="dumps"></div>
</body>
    <script>
      var targetContainer = document.getElementById("dumps");
      var eventSource = new EventSource("/stream");
      eventSource.onmessage = function(e) {
          targetContainer.innerHTML = e.data;
      };
    </script>
</html>
```

My issue:

The outputs seems to get to the browser but any new streamed output overwrites the previous one. For e.g. the following is all i see in the browser and the line keeps changing as stream is updated:

```
Output

b'\t0x0020: 8011 01fa ce65 0000 0101 080a 1984 6ce7 .....e........l.\n'   <=== keeps updating
```

What i'd like to achieve is a stream of tcpdump output rendered on my browser as an actual bash output would look like.

This works fine if i point to url path `/stream` and the reason why i'm embedding into html is to be able to give it some style.

Answer (score 0):

Changed to `targetContainer.innerHTML += e.data + "<br/>` in `<script>`